# Drivers for portable scanners

Tags: drivers

I am trying to install the driver for a Brother DSmobile 720D scanner in Ubuntu 14.04 but can't seem to find the driver anywhere. Is there a driver for this machine, or can anyone recommend a similar product that has drivers available in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Download the Driver from The Brother Web Site

To check if you running 32bit or 64bit.
run this command

```
uname -a
```

Result for 32-bit Ubuntu:

> Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 **i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**

whereas the 64-bit Ubuntu will show:

> Linux discworld 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 **x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**
>   if you are running a 32Bit version of Ubuntu.

run these commands if you are on 32bit

```
wget http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf100975/libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_i386.deb 

sudo dpkg -i --force-all  libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_i386.deb
```

if you are running 64Bit run these commands.

```
wget http://download.brother.com/welcome/dlf100976/libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-all  libsane-dsseries_1.0.5-1_amd64.deb
```

[Brother Scanner driver How to Install](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadhowto.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=ds720d_all&os=128&dlid=dlf100975_000&flang=4&type3=565)